# Publishing Web Module in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, web, module

I have come across an error when trying to deploy a webmodule to a tomcat server in Eclipse Luna. The error message is not very helpful. And i would like some help in tracking down the cause. The error i get is

```
Could not publish to the server.
org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.flatfile cannot be cast to      org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.IFlatFolder.
```

Any suggestions on how to interpret the message would be nice. I have tried in various ways to edit the web deployment assembly.

The only other thread covering this issue is this one, that did not get an answer

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1065433/?srch=flatfile+cannot+be+cast#msg_1065433

Comment: got the same problem here. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your workspace may have been corrupted. I tried a number of approaches; different server runtimes, different version of Eclipse. I couldn't get past this until I created a new workspace, loaded my projects into it and set up a new server runtime.